# I am trying to click a button/element on a popup window using Selenium2Library in Robotframework .But I get the following error in Robotframework

Tags: python, html, xpath, robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to click a button/element on a popup window using Selenium 2 Library in Robot framework, but I get an error.

This is the code:

```
Test Click Like
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //iframe[@title="Facebook Social Plugin"]
    Select Frame    //iframe[@title="Facebook Social Plugin"]
    #Frame Should Contain    //*[@id="u_0_0"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/img[@src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yi/r/odA9sNLrE86.jpg"]
    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id='u_0_0']/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[1]/em/*[@data-intl-translation="Thích"]
    Sleep    5s
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//*[@id='u_0_0']/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[1]/em/*[@data-intl-translation="Bỏ thích"]
    Sleep    5s
    Capture Page Screenshot
```

This is the error:

```
Error
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//*[@id='u_0_0']/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[1]/em/*[@data-intl-translation="Thích"]' did not match any elements.
```

I have this HTML code:

```
<a href="#">
<em class="_4qba" data-intl-translation="Thích" data-intl-trid="">Thích</em>
</a>
```

Comment: Please edit this to be more readable.

Comment: And what is the question, exactly?

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory: your xpath doesn't lead to an element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select that pop-up window first for performing any actions on that opened pop-up window.